# Iterate function to search for a key on Firebase, Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am making an app where you enter a number in an EditText, if that number matches with some key from the database in Firebase it will show up the value of that key in a TextView.

Here's the structure of the database:
[Structure DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iBKQ.png)

**The problem i have** is that when i enter "1" in my EditText and it searches for the key that matches with it in the database i can retrieve the value of it because it's the first child (i guess) but when i enter another key (2-5) it says that doesn't exists because of the else sentence in my code.
I think i'm not iterating the full database so i can retrieve the correct value.

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private TextView mEstado ;
private Button B_buscar;
private EditText E_buscar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("no_orden");

    mEstado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.estado);

    B_buscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B_buscar);

    E_buscar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.E_buscar);

    B_buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String buscar = E_buscar.getText().toString().trim();


            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        DataSnapshot estado = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
                        if (estado.getKey().toString().equals(buscar)){
                            mEstado.setText("The number #" + buscar + " contains: " + estado);

                        }else{
                            if (buscar.equals("")){
                                mEstado.setText("Enter a valid number.");
                            }else {
                                mEstado.setText("The number #" + buscar + " doesn't exists.");
                            }
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}}
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **for** iterator like this:

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Key: "+postSnapshot.getKey());
                Log.d(TAG, "Value: "+postSnapshot.getValue());
            }
```

Comment: Nice i can see it works in the Android Monitor
Can you tell if im doing it right in the if sentence?
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + postSnapshot.getKey());
                            Log.d(TAG, "Value: " + postSnapshot.getValue());
                            if (postSnapshot.getKey().equals(buscar){
                                mEstado.setText("The number #" + buscar + " contains: " + postSnapshot.getValue());

Because im still getting not the value when i run the app.. only in the android monitor

Comment: Maybe because you're using equals() that is only to compare Strings, the value that retrieve postSnapshot is an integer, try to compare them with ==

Comment: Well actually i got it to work with equals but i'm only able to retrieve the last value.. i mean in the monitor seems to save those 5 keys with the respective values but if i enter between the key 1 to 4 in the EditText i get "Doesn't exist" but if I ask for the 5th one i can retrieve it correctly.

Comment: I don't know, but it doesn't seem that the problem is there, search in other parts of your code.

Comment: Well thank you anyways i will try to understand what's going on.. so far your code helped me 

Comment: You also can try passing to a List the values that you got and then compare them outside in other method.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to send a string called buscar and you want to check its existance, I suggest you do this :

```
   @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

             //in this part of your code use this

              if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(buscar)){

                //this means the number is found in the database
               }else{

                //this means the number is not found in the database
               }



                    }
```